# Multiply a matrix by reference values contained in a second matrix of different dimension

Tags: r, matrix

I am working in R.

I have two `tibbles`/`data.frames` of values both indexed by a column `year`.

While the first of the tibbles - `df` - is the one containing the values for `n years` (which are not necessarily unique, but can be), the second one - `df1`  - contains some multiplicative values of the first for each `year` (in this case just `unique(year)` values).

What I want to do is to multiply each element of the first matrix by the correct reference from the second matrix.

```
Year <- c("2010", "2010", "2011", "2011")
value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)          
df <- as_tibble(value) %>% add_column(Year= Year)

Year1<- c("2010", "2011")
value1 <- c(100, 200)

df1 <- as_tibble(value1) %>% add_column(Year1= Year1)
```

The result for this example should be this (but scalable for dynamic `dim(df)` / `dim(df1)`:

```
result <- c(100, 200, 600, 800)
res <- as_tibble(result) %>% add_column(Year = Year)
```

Any idea how can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `merge`

```
transform(
  merge(df, df1, by.x = "Year", by.y = "Year1"),
  value = value.x * value.y
)[names(df)]
```

which gives

```
  value Year
1   100 2010
2   200 2010
3   600 2011
4   800 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do a join `by` the 'Year' columns and then multiply the 'value' columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    left_join(df1, by = c('Year' = 'Year1')) %>%
    transmute(value = value.x * value.y, Year)
```

---

Or use `data.table` join and assign (`:=`) the 'value' by multiplying the 'value' with the 'value' column of the second dataset (`i.value`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[as.data.table(df1), value := value * i.value, on = .(Year = Year1)]
```